# What's the difference between "buy up" "buy down" "buy" and "purchase"

Tags: meaning, differences

What's the different between:

- Buy up
- buy down
- purchase
- buy

When they're all supposed to mean "to pay money"?

Comment: In what context?   What have you learned from your research?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They don't all mean "to pay money" - in fact none of them mean just that.

"Buy" means "to pay money *and obtain something*" i.e. you pay money in exchange for the product or service. This is the verb form. 
In noun form it means the item that was bought.

"Purchase" is a synonym for buy and means the same when used as a verb and noun.

"Buy up" means to buy everything available in the store.

```
She bought up all the shoes that were on sale.
```

["Buydown" is a financial term](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/buydown.asp#ixzz1Pu1TxNlo) used to mean paying off some part of a loan and reducing interest rates.

> A mortgage-financing technique with
>   which the buyer attempts to obtain a
>   lower interest rate for at least the
>   first few years of the mortgage, but
>   possibly its entire life.

Comment: Maybe i'm hallucinating, but I think you can use "buy up" with quantities other than "all". Like, "I bought up most of those great bananas" or, "I bought up some onions". "Up" used in this way, to my understanding, indicates that the item is of limited quantity, and implies that you are contributing to its elimination. Similar to "to use up", "to free up", et al. "I bought up some bananas" seems to imply that maybe it's the end of the season and there is a limited quantity. I think without any quantity specified does imply a quantity of "all" though.

Answer (score 0):

Buy-Up - investor's lingo
http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/buy_up.asp

> Points paid by a lender to a borrower
>   or mortgage broker for a loan with an
>   above-market interest rate.

but may also refer to [buying everything of a given item](http://mw1.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buy%20up)

Buy-down - mortgage lingo
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buydown

> financing technique where the buyer
>   attempts to obtain a lower interest
>   rate for at least the first few years
>   of the mortgage

[Purchase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchasing) Aquire something for money - synonym of **Buy**

Answer (score 0):

["Buy"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/buy), and ["purchase"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/purchase) all mean the same thing: to pay money to acquire a possesion.

The difference is ["buy down" which is a :](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/buy+down)

> a subsidy for a long-term mortgage offered by a third party, as a builder or developer, to lower interest rates for a buyer in the early years of the loan.

Edit: "Buy up" has a nuance that "buy" and "purchase" doesn't have, and [that is:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/buy+up)

> to purchase all, or all that is available, of (something)